# Posting data of a single table row when table is in one form

Tags: html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have one form that has a whole table inside it. A `for` loop iterates through a list of items and adds records to the table. Each record has a submit button. When I click that button, I use AJAX to serialize 
and POST the form (because I need to reload a partial), and expect to POST data about that single item in the record to the controller.

In other words, if a table is displaying records from a looped list, I want to be able to POST a single list item to the controller.

What is holding me back is the `for` and `foreach` loops when I try to POST a record:

- If I use a `foreach` loop the form always POSTs the very first record in the table, even if I click the button on other records.
- If I use a `for` loop I am required to POST the whole list to my controller because the list is a parameter inside another object. This means I am forced to bind to the model that contains the list.

Possible reason for the issue: I suspect this has something to do with the values of the `name` attributes in the HTML that `asp-for` attribute generates. With a `for` loop the names are not unique, so the binding process assumes the first record with the correct names. With a `foreach` loop, the names are unique, but the binding process needs to bind to the model that contains the list.

HTML View (simplified). A `foreach` loop in place of the `for` loop would look like `@foreach (var shipment in lineItem.Shipments) { <tr>... </tr> }`

```
@model OrderTrackingContract.SalesOrder

@foreach (var lineItem in Model.LineItems)
{
    <table class="lineItemTables">
        //line items table
    </table>

    @if (lineItem.Shipments.Count > 0)
    {
        <form method="post">
            <table class="table shipmentTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            ShipmentID
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Qty Shipped
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Actions
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @for (int i = 0; i < lineItem.Shipments.Count; i++)
                    {

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input id="shipmentID" asp-for="@lineItem.Shipments[i].ShipmentID" />
                            </td>
                            <td>    
                                <input id="qtyShipped" asp-for="@lineItem.Shipments[i].QtyShipped" value="@lineItem.Shipments[i].QtyShipped" min="1" max="999" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="updateButton" type="submit" value="Update" />
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    }
}
```

AJAX

```
$('.updateButton').on('click', function () {
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    form.submit(function (event) {

        event.preventDefault(); /* stop form from submitting normally */

        $.ajax({
            url: "/OrderTracking/UpdateShipment",
            type: "POST",
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function () {
                //some code here
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Controller Action

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UpdateShipment(Shipment shipment)
{
    _orderTrackingService.UpdateShipmentByID(shipment.ShipmentID, shipment.QtyShipped);

    return NoContent();
}
```

I have tried to extract the values from the tags using the tag ids `shipmentID` and `qtyShipped` closest to the button and pass them to the controller, which worked. However, I want to avoid doing that and instead actually POST the form.

Comment: Well if you only want to post a single row, you shouldn't be using `form.serialize()` in your ajax request. This will serialize EVERY row and post it because you have your form wrapping every row. Either use a form for each row or just manual create the `data` object to be passed to your action.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If I try to wrap my table rows or table cells in a form, I get a message that says I cannot nest the elements like that. I am not sure what you mean when you say " create the ```data``` object to be passed to your action".

Comment: Yes, if you had a form for every row you would have to update your HTML a bunch. I posted an answer below of the other method I mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to pass data for a single row then just get the data for that row and pass to your action... don't serialize every row and post it.

You should do 2 things...

First update the inputs in your loop by giving them a class and not an `id`. `id`'s should be unique for the page, but you are creating the same `id="shipmentID"` and `id="qtyShipped"` for your inputs. Don't do this, the `asp-for` will create your `id` and `name` attributes for you.

```
            <tbody>
                @for (int i = 0; i < lineItem.Shipments.Count; i++)
                {

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input class="shipmentID" asp-for="@lineItem.Shipments[i].ShipmentID" />
                        </td>
                        <td>    
                            <input class="qtyShipped" asp-for="@lineItem.Shipments[i].QtyShipped" value="@lineItem.Shipments[i].QtyShipped" min="1" max="999" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="updateButton" type="submit" value="Update" />
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
```

Next, update your ajax request to find the row the button is in then get the values of the inputs of that row and make a data object to be passed to your action. Like this:

```
$('.updateButton').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); /* stop form from submitting normally */

    var row = $(this).closest('tr'),
        shipmentID = $('.shipmentID', row),
        qtyShipped = $('.qtyShipped', row);

    var data = { ShipmentID: shipmentID.val(), QtyShipped: qtyShipped.val() };

    $.ajax({
        url: "/OrderTracking/UpdateShipment",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function () {
            //some code here
        }
    });
});
```

You were also attaching a `submit` event to your form everytime a submit button was clicked. This is bad and would result in 3 submit events being attached if 3 buttons were clicked, so I removed this.

Comment: Thank you, the solution makes sense. You are preventing the form from submitting and then extracting raw values from the row. From what I can gather, I wouldn't even need to have a form in this case, since I'd grab the values straight from the tags?

Comment: That is correct you technically don't need it. I think you might even be able to do a `data: row.serialize()` which will just serialize the inputs in that row.

Comment: The suggestion to serialize just the row was the solution I was looking for. I don't have to worry about extracting many values independently and I don't require a form. This frees me up to make some other changes. Thanks a lot.