# Posting row model data from a table within a form (no JS)

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I ran into an almost identical issue before and posted a question about it here: [Posting data of a single table row when table is in one form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58984061/posting-data-of-a-single-table-row-when-table-is-in-one-form) We were able to solve it but it felt pretty hacky. To summarize that post, I was attempting to use AJAX and JS to POST values from a table row to a controller. The problem was that every row would be serialized within the form. To solve this, I serialized only the row I needed.

This time I am running into the same issue, the only difference being that I'm not using AJAX and am submitting the model data from the table row directly to the controller action.

I tried to use both the `foreach` and `for` loops to generate table rows. 
The `foreach` loop always POSTs the first row in the table, even if I click submit button on the second row.
The `for` loop doesn't POST anything, or at least I get all null values in my controller action's "shipment" parameter.

I also tried to encase the row in a form, but HTML does not allow to have a `<form>` in `<tbody>`.

What I want is to be be able to POST a single row (generated by looping through a list for models) directly to the "UpdateShipment" controller action. All of this without using AJAX.

HTML code:

```
@model OrderTrackingContract.SalesOrder

@foreach (var lineItem in Model.LineItems)
{
    <table class="lineItemTables">
        //line items table
    </table>

    @if (lineItem.Shipments.Count > 0)
    {
        <form method="post">
            <table class="table shipmentTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            ShipmentID
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Qty Shipped
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Actions
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @for (int i = 0; i < lineItem.Shipments.Count; i++)
                    {

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input class="shipmentID" asp-for="@lineItem.Shipments[i].ShipmentID" />
                            </td>
                            <td>    
                                <input class="qtyShipped" asp-for="@lineItem.Shipments[i].QtyShipped" value="@lineItem.Shipments[i].QtyShipped" min="1" max="999" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="updateButton" type="submit" value="Update" asp-action="UpdateShipment" asp-controller="Shipments" />
                                <input class="deleteButton" type="submit" value="Delete" asp-route-shipmentID="@lineItem.Shipments[i].ShipmentID" asp-action="DeleteShipment" asp-controller="Shipments" />
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    }
}
```

Controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UpdateShipment(Shipment shipment)
{
    _orderTrackingService.UpdateShipmentByID(shipment.ShipmentID, shipment.QtyShipped);

    return NoContent();
}
```

EDIT: I used fiddler and I'm starting to understand what's going on. Both `for` and `foreach` loop submit the whole form because the whole table is in it.

Using a `for` loop I am forced to write `asp-for="@lineItem.Shipments[i].ShipmentID"`, which means the controller must accept a parameter of `LineItem lineItem`.

Using `foreach` loop I am able to write `asp-for="@shipment.ShipmentID`, but because the generated attributes of the `<input>` are identical, the 'Shipment shipment' parameter binds to the first values POSTed.

Comment: One simple solution is to generate multiple tables with one row, instead of a table with multiple rows. Then control the style with CSS, so it looks like a single table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want is to be be able to POST a single row (generated by looping through a list for models) directly to the "UpdateShipment" controller action. All of this without using AJAX.

To achieve above requirement, you can try to generate `<form>` and `<table>` for each `Shipment` item, like below.

```
@foreach (var lineItem in Model.LineItems)
{
    <table class="table shipmentTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    ShipmentID
                </th>
                <th>
                    Qty Shipped
                </th>
                <th>
                    Actions
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

    @if (lineItem.Shipments.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var Shipment in lineItem.Shipments)
        {
            <form method="post">
                <table class="table shipmentTable">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input class="shipmentID" asp-for="@Shipment.ShipmentID" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="qtyShipped" asp-for="@Shipment.QtyShipped" value="@Shipment.QtyShipped" min="1" max="999" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="updateButton" type="submit" value="Update" asp-action="UpdateShipment" asp-controller="Shipments" />
                                <input class="deleteButton" type="submit" value="Delete" asp-route-shipmentID="@Shipment.ShipmentID" asp-action="DeleteShipment" asp-controller="Shipments" />
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
        }
    }
}
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It is a bit strange to have multiple tables for each row, but it's a solution that's functional and can be worked with.