# how to pass two values in a form inside a table row to the controller ? Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I make this table

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Price
                </th>
                <th>
                    Quantity
                </th>
                <th>
                    Options
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.Name</td>
                    <td>@item.Price</td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="Quantity"/> </td>
                    <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add" /></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>

    </table>
```

To work like the table below (this one works fine)

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%" >
                   <thead>
                       <tr>
                           <th>                            
                               Name
                           </th>
                           <th>
                               Prrice
                           </th>
                           <th>
                               Quantity
                           </th>
                           <th class="text-center">
                               Options
                           </th>
                       </tr>
                   </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach(var item in Model)
                        {
                        <tr>
                            <td width="55%">@item.Name</td>
                            <td width="10%" class="text-right">@item.Price $</td>
                            <td width="10%" class="text-right">@item.Quantity</td>
                            <td width="25%">
                                <div class="w-100 btn-group"role="group">
                                    <a asp-controller="item" asp-action="Update" asp- asp-route-Id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-outline-primary mx-1">Update</a>
                                    <a asp-controller="item" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-Id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-outline-danger mx-1">Delete</a>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

I want to pass the item.quantity and item.id to the controller.

Item model

```
public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public float Price { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

I found that you can put each item in a table and a form for each one [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59709994/13831823),  but I would like to know if with asp.net it can be made simpler

Comment: Create a ViewModel

Comment: Does `Precio` and `Cantidad` are `Price` and `Quantity`?I think creating a form is the easiest way as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to post ALL ROW VALUES (assuming each row is a different object) then use a form outside the table and take needed properties into inputs in order to get posted.

If you need to post SINGLE ROW VALUES (only submit the row where the value is beign modified) then you could write some JS and make a post or ajax post of all inputs in the current row.

```
$(document).on('keypress', 'input[data-ajax="row"]', function (e) {
if (e.keyCode !== 13) {
    return;
}

var self = $(this);
var row = self.closest('tr');
var url = '/controller/action';

var propertyNames = new Array();
var propertyValues = new Array();
row.find('input[data-ajax="row"]').each(function () {
    $(this).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
    propertyNames.push($(this).attr('id'));
    propertyValues.push($(this).val());
});

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: { propertyNames, propertyValues },
    success: function (data) {
        //SUCCESS CODE HERE (reload)
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log('error');
        alert('error');
    }
});

return;
```

});

Note that you will need to add `data-ajax="row"` attribute to your input. Alsou you could remove the dynamic code and find all needed controls inside the row scope.
Ej: `var name = row.find('#name').val()`

Comment: I'm going to do the js with ajax , ty !